# ¿Cómo utilizar Git para trabajar en un mismo proyecto en un equipo diferentes?

Tags: github

Tengo la duda de trabajar con github en 2 ordenadores, realice la actualizacion para autenticar mi cuenta. Ahora quiero trabajar desde casa y en la oficina(no desarrollo) pero estoy aprendiendo, antes clonaba el repositorio y podia trabajar normal. Ahora para descargar o subir los cambios me pide usuario y la contraseña de ese usuario, ingreso mis credenciales y manda el mensaje de que las credenciales están mal. Alguien me puede orientar si los datos que ingreso son para el acceso a mi Github.

Comment: Si te dice que las credenciales están mal, lo están. Otra forma más sencilla es generar una clave SSH en tu computadora y registrarla en tu cuenta de Github. Recuerda guardar esta clave y ponerla en cada ordenador nuevo.

Comment: Consulta los manuales de Git con el error que te dice de credenciales. Una opcion es que este tomando las credenciales globales y estas no concuerdan con tu repositorio.